# Media 3 Player Not Play Video With Media Session

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, android-mediasession, android-media3

I'm making sample app with Media 3 It's working fine without media session but when i add media session in it it's give me error below I've attacehed code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Media3Demo"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyMediaService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService"/>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var playerView: PlayerView
    private lateinit var controllerFuture: ListenableFuture<MediaController>
    private lateinit var controller: MediaController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        playerView = findViewById(R.id.video_view)
    }
    
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        val sessionToken = SessionToken(this, ComponentName(this, MyMediaService::class.java))
        controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(this, sessionToken).buildAsync()
        controllerFuture.addListener(
            {
                controller = controllerFuture.get()
                initController()
                val url = "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" 
                play(url)
            },
            MoreExecutors.directExecutor()
        )
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        MediaController.releaseFuture(controllerFuture)
        super.onStop()
    }

    private fun initController() {
        //controller.playWhenReady = true
        controller.addListener(object : Player.Listener {

            override fun onMediaMetadataChanged(mediaMetadata: MediaMetadata) {
                super.onMediaMetadataChanged(mediaMetadata)
                log("onMediaMetadataChanged=$mediaMetadata")
            }

            override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
                super.onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying)
                log("onIsPlayingChanged=$isPlaying")
            }

            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
                log("onPlaybackStateChanged=${getStateName(playbackState)}")
            }

            override fun onPlayerError(error: PlaybackException) {
                super.onPlayerError(error)
                log("onPlayerError=${error.stackTraceToString()}")
            }

            override fun onPlayerErrorChanged(error: PlaybackException?) {
                super.onPlayerErrorChanged(error)
                log("onPlayerErrorChanged=${error?.stackTraceToString()}")
            }
        })
        log("start=${getStateName(controller.playbackState)}")
        log("COMMAND_PREPARE=${controller.isCommandAvailable(COMMAND_PREPARE)}")
        log("COMMAND_SET_MEDIA_ITEM=${controller.isCommandAvailable(COMMAND_SET_MEDIA_ITEM)}")
        log("COMMAND_PLAY_PAUSE=${controller.isCommandAvailable(COMMAND_PLAY_PAUSE)}")
    }

    private fun play(url: String) {
        playerView.player = controller
        val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
            .setUri(url)
            .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_MPD)
            .build()

        controller.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        controller.prepare()
        controller.play()
    }

    private fun getStateName(i: Int): String? {
        return when (i) {
            1 -> "STATE_IDLE"
            2 -> "STATE_BUFFERING"
            3 -> "STATE_READY"
            4 -> "STATE_ENDED"
            else -> null
        }
    }
}
```

MyMediaService.kt

```
class MyMediaService : MediaSessionService(), MediaSession.Callback {

    private var mediaSession: MediaSession? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        mediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, player).setCallback(this).build()
    }

    override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaSession? =
        mediaSession

    override fun onDestroy() {
        mediaSession?.run {
            player.release()
            release()
            mediaSession = null
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onAddMediaItems(
        mediaSession: MediaSession,
        controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo,
        mediaItems: MutableList<MediaItem>
    ): ListenableFuture<MutableList<MediaItem>> {
        val updatedMediaItems =
            mediaItems.map { it.buildUpon().setUri(it.mediaId).build() }.toMutableList()
        return Futures.immediateFuture(updatedMediaItems)
    }

}
```

build.gradle(depndencies)

```
 implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.media3:media3-session:1.1.0")
```

Error
Playback error
androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:684)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:656)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: androidx.media3.datasource.FileDataSource$FileDataSourceException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at androidx.media3.datasource.FileDataSource.openLocalFile(FileDataSource.java:205)
at androidx.media3.datasource.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:116)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:272)
at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:101)
at androidx.media3.datasource.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:64)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:180)
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: : open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:574)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:289)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:152)
at androidx.media3.datasource.FileDataSource.openLocalFile(FileDataSource.java:186)
at androidx.media3.datasource.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:116) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:272) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:101) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:64) 
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:180) 
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) 
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:563)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:274)
at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.open(ForwardingOs.java:563)
at android.app.ActivityThread$AndroidOs.open(ActivityThread.java:8172)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:560)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:289) 
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:152) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.FileDataSource.openLocalFile(FileDataSource.java:186) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.FileDataSource.open(FileDataSource.java:116) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:272) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:86) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.DataSourceInputStream.checkOpened(DataSourceInputStream.java:101) 
at androidx.media3.datasource.DataSourceInputStream.open(DataSourceInputStream.java:64) 
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.ParsingLoadable.load(ParsingLoadable.java:180) 
at androidx.media3.exoplayer.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:414) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

any help is appricated